# Sharing internet access - solid way to guarantee good bandwidth for VoIP and gaming?

Tags: bandwidth, tomato, qos

we have a linksys E2500 here

The internet connection is a low 2 mbit with 1 mbit upload. The connection is shared by around 16 people (yayyy).

I want teamviewer, skype, VoIP work well, as well as a casual game of Dota 2 or HOS.

I have the ability to flash the router I guess, since I am in contact with the owner.

What is my best bet and how to do it?

What I read is, QoS of linksys standard firmware is for outgoing traffic only. I read there are working custom firmwares that control the incoming traffic as well (by delaying tcp ack responses etc i guess)

But I don't know which settings would be good to make the bandwidth leave me in without making other users very unhappy.

Point is, even if i could talk the owner into increasing bandwidth in general, it will probably still cause lag since 16 people can cause lag very easily even with 10 mbit.

Comment: Most of the stuff you want to use are require a good amount of bandwidth.  You need a better internet connection before all 16 people will be able to use all those services.  You have a bottom of the barrel router, it doesn't support 802.11ac which is one of the only ways you will be able to support high bandwidth services to 16+ clients.

Comment: it's plain wrong. I mean sure, 16 clients is a lot but even 10 mbit can be too little for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can [flash DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) (paste `E2500` and install the webflash).

This is [The DDwrt QoS wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service). But with that low internet connection between 16 people I doubt that you will achieve something.

Comment: i read about toastman tomato, seems to be what everyone is looking for

Comment: @Toskan you can use whatever you want. There is Tomato, DD-wrt, Openwrt and they are all custom firmwares. I personally use DDwrt but you can try them all and see what suits you best. Just know that some thirdparty firmwares have some bugs in QoS and doesnt control very well the trafic. You should test and then relay on them. It is not always out of the box solution.

Comment: that's what i am saying, toastman is known for his QoS solutions, that's what he's well known for. Shibby tomatousb implements his QoS config as well. It works kinda well, needs some fine tuning but as far as now, I am quite happy.